# How to append inconsistently ordered log file data to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, append

I need to process a list of log files and convert string data in those files to one dataframe for analysis. Each log file contains one or more pairs of lines corresponding to an ID, an error occurrence, and the time the error cleared. But if there were several simultaneous errors on different IDs, the errors are listed on consecutive lines as a group, and then the corresponding "cleared" lines are listed as a group.

I can split strings for each row of data, and I can append new rows to the dataframe easily enough. But I don't know how to combine the date from each pair of lines into one row in the df, especially because they aren't necessarily ordered one pair at a time.

Simplified example log file ("example.log" in the code below):

```
ID1 Error code A
ID1 Error cleared: 00:01:00
ID2 Error code B
ID3 Error code B
ID4 Error code A
ID2 Error cleared: 00:02:00
ID3 Error cleared: 00:02:00
ID4 Error cleared: 00:02:00
ID5 Error code B
ID5 Error cleared: 00:03:00
ID2 Error code A
ID2 Error cleared: 00:04:00
ID6 Error code A
ID6 Error cleared: 00:05:00
```

Desired dataframe:

```
    TID     ERROR   CLEARED
0   ID1     A       00:01:00
1   ID2     B       00:02:00
2   ID3     B       00:02:00
3   ID4     A       00:02:00
4   ID5     B       00:03:00
5   ID2     A       00:04:00
6   ID6     A       00:05:00
```

This code yields a df with all the data in correct columns, but with a row for each line of the log. I'd like to have only 1 line for each pair of error/time-cleared data.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
with open('example.log') as file:
    for line in file: 
        part = line.split()
        tid=part[0]
        if 'code' in line:
            error=part[3] 
        if 'cleared' in line: 
            time=part[3]
        dfx=pd.DataFrame([[tid,error,time]],columns=['TID','ERROR','CLEARED'])
        df=df.append(dfx, ignore_index=True)
        tid=''
        error=''
        time=''
```

Results in too many unnecessary rows:

```
    TID     ERROR   CLEARED
0   ID1     A   
1   ID1             00:01:00
2   ID2     B   
3   ID3     B   
4   ID4     A   
5   ID2             00:02:00
6   ID3             00:02:00
7   ID4             00:02:00
8   ID5     B   
9   ID5             00:03:00
10  ID2     A   
11  ID2             00:04:00
12  ID6     A   
13  ID6             00:05:00
```

If I indent the last few lines so the new rows build only after a "cleared" line, it's close to what I want, but the errors do not populate correctly.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
with open('example.log') as file:
    for line in file: 
        part = line.split()
        tid=part[0]
        if 'code' in line:
            error=part[3] 
        if 'cleared' in line: 
            time=part[3]
            dfx=pd.DataFrame([[tid,error,time]],columns=['TID','ERROR','CLEARED'])
            df=df.append(dfx, ignore_index=True)
            tid=''
            error=''
            time=''
```

Results in one row per occurrence, but inconsistent data in ERROR column:

```
    TID     ERROR   CLEARED
0   ID1     A       00:01:00
1   ID2     A       00:02:00
2   ID3             00:02:00
3   ID4             00:02:00
4   ID5     B       00:03:00
5   ID2     A       00:04:00
6   ID6     A       00:05:00
```

Can someone please help me pull the data into the dataframe so the errors line up correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: don't you have any missing data?

Comment: on the other hand, you presume that TID's are unique?

Comment: There is no missing data (see example log). TIDs may repeat if there is another occurrence of an error. I have done this in the example: ID2 appears with error code B (cleared at 00:02:00) and ID2 appears later with error code A (cleared at 00:04:00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with some similar like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

data = """
ID1 Error code A
ID1 Error cleared: 00:01:00
ID2 Error code B
ID3 Error code B
ID4 Error code A
ID2 Error cleared: 00:02:00
ID3 Error cleared: 00:02:00
ID4 Error cleared: 00:02:00
ID5 Error code B
ID5 Error cleared: 00:03:00
ID2 Error code A
ID2 Error cleared: 00:04:00
ID6 Error code A
ID6 Error cleared: 00:05:00
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=' ',header=None,names=["ID", "ER", "CODE", "ERROR"])
df['CLEARED'] = np.where(df['CODE']=='cleared:', df['ERROR'], np.nan)
df=df.bfill()
df=df.loc[df['CODE'] == 'code']
#df=df.drop(['ER','CODE'], inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df.drop(['ER', 'CODE'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True))
```

result:

```
    ID ERROR   CLEARED
0  ID1     A  00:01:00
1  ID2     B  00:02:00
2  ID3     B  00:02:00
3  ID4     A  00:02:00
4  ID5     B  00:03:00
5  ID2     A  00:04:00
6  ID6     A  00:05:00
```

Comment: Thank you, GiovaniSalazar
I have added df.bfill() to my bag of tricks.